# passing argparse dict shaped string from pycharm to a remote interperter (local win,remote nix)

Tags: python, dictionary, pycharm, remote-debugging, argparse

I have the following config:

pycharm on a local win7 machine using a remote unix machine as an interpreter.

The code I'm trying to run receives a dict format string from argparse and uses eval to make it into a dict.

this works when running through ssh but fails running from pycharm using script parameters,

I've been able to use \ for escaping both } and " as so:

```
--input_paths \{\"kk1\":\[\"/sandbox/23\"]\}
```

but adding more keys:

```
 --input_paths \{\"kk1\":[\"/sandbox/23\"],\"kk2\":[\"/sandbox/23\"]\}
```

results in:

```
 argtest.py: error: unrecognized arguments: "kk2":["/sandbox/23"]}
```

any ideas?

Comment: I think you are not escaping the ']' just before the ',' before kk2, right ?

Comment: you're right, but it makes no difference (I think escaping the ] is not needed I'l edit the question in a sec)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

May be its too late, but i figured out that you need to have parameters like.

```
    {\"kk1\":\"asd\",\"kk2\":\"asd\"}
```

Single quotes and double quotes also matters in my experience.

Hope this helps someone.